# MessageDefinitionSends Rest API successful response but never sends email

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud

I'm getting a successful response (202 code with empty response body), but my email neither sends nor looks to be queued.

POST to https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:expenseit_test_triggered_send/send?access_token=[token]

with headers:

- Authorization: Bearer [token]
- Content-Type: application/json

and payload:

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "sender@domain.com", 
        "Name": "Sender"
    }, 
    "To": {
        "Address": "recipient@domain.com", 
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "City": "Seatle", 
                "State": "WA"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I mis-using the endpoint?  Is there another endpoint that I should use to verify the status of this message?

Comment: You just receive an Id in the response body for successful Api calls.  Your request looks OK.  Can you try adding: "Options": {
    "RequestType": "SYNC"
  } at the same level as From and To.

Comment: Please check that Test, Proof or Draft are not in subject or preheader, check if FROM(Address here): is a valid user in marketing cloud. check the structure that @Mac wrote that is correct for POSTMAN test(check if the suscriber already exists in marketing cloud too).

Answer (score 1):

SubscriberKey is a required property.  If there is not a unique ID that is being used for subscribers, then just pass the same value you are passing for Address.

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "sender@domain.com", 
        "Name": "Sender"
    }, 
    "To": {
        "Address": "recipient@domain.com", 
        "SubscriberKey": "recipient@domain.com", 
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "City": "Seatle", 
                "State": "WA"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same results with and without the SubscriberKey

Comment: Any required attributes in the account that aren't being passed in the request?

Comment: I thought `SubscriberKey` was optional? Should the [docs](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/messaging-messagedefinitionsends-send) get updated?

Comment: How would I tell which attributes are required?  And the [documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/messaging-messagedefinitionsends-send) does indicate that SubscriberKey is optional.

Comment: @BrianLund Required attributes can be viewed in ExactTarget Email by going to Subscribers > Profile Management, then sort by the Required column to see all those that are required at the top.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Looks like the documentation was wrong, it is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this issue as well. The solution to our problem was actually quite simple, but not obvious. We had to select the template in the admin and hit the "Start/Restart" button. ExactTarget may want to consider throwing a more useful error message here.