# Rest API says email is queued but never shows up in web frontend or sends email

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, rest, send-email

I'm using the REST API to send emails and currently have five test emails. Two of these never go to a 'Queued' status in the Triggered Send definitions after hitting the API, despite getting a `202 Accepted` response. All responses from the API have `hasErrors: "false"` and `messages: ["Queued"]` in the JSON reply.

I'm testing using curl with the command

```
curl -i --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer <token>" --data @key:failing_template.json https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:failing_template/send
```

and with the following data in the file `failing_template.json`

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "test-recipient@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "test-recipient@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "MemberFirstName": "Test Firstname",
                "MemberLastName": "Test Lastname",
                "SomeAmount": 123.45
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's pretty much no difference between what I'm sending for API calls which actually end up sending an email and ones that don't.

Things I've checked

- Triggered Send has any changes published and is started.
- External Key in the Triggered Send matches the `key` value in the API URL.
- Triggered Send is associated with the correct DE.
- All data sent has correct names and values for the DE associated with the Triggered Send.
- Changing the external key of the triggered send and saving and publishing changes.

Similar to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25190/messagedefinitionsends-rest-api-successful-response-but-never-sends-email), which appears to not have been resolved either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually turned out to be an issue with data types, both of which return `202 Accepted` headers from the API but then silently fail, never to be seen again.

### Number fields don't like decimals

Sending a decimal or string with a decimal in it to a field that expects a number succeeds from the API end, but fails somewhere between the API endpoint and the Triggered Send.

For example, if both the `First` and `Second` columns in the DE have the data type `Number` then this will fail

```
"First": 1234.56,
"Second": "1234.56"
```

But this will succeed

```
"First": 1234,
"Second": 1234
```

I didn't test a quoted field with an integer. In all fairness this should have been expected, since [the documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/data_types/) does say

> You cannot import decimal values into a column with this data type. If you need to import decimal values, use the Decimal data type instead

### Date fields are finicky

This one was a little weirder, despite the documentation saying

> - Attributes of a date type will accept dates in various formats, such as 1/1/2005 or January 1, 2005
> - You can add a HH:MM time value following the date value, such as 12/12/2012 12:12 PM.

The following date formats seem to fail due to D-M-Y formatting despite any locale settings. The expected format seems to be M-D-Y

```
"DateField": "21-11-2014",
"DateField": "21-11-2014 11:29",
"DateField": "21-11-2014 11:29 PM",
"DateField": "21/11/2014",
"DateField": "21/11/2014 11:29",
"DateField": "21/11/2014 11:29 PM",
```

The following seem to fail due to inclusion of a timezone

```
"DateField": "21 November 2014 11:29 PM EST",
"DateField": "21 November 2014 23:29 EST",
```

The following seem to work, since they either do Y-M-D formatting or are in the expected "D F Y" format.

```
"DateField": "2014-11-21 11:29",
"DateField": "2014-11-21 11:29 PM",
"DateField": "2014/11/21 11:29",
"DateField": "2014/11/21 11:29 PM",
"DateField": "21 November 2014",
"DateField": "21 November 2014 11:29",
"DateField": "21 November 2014 11:29 PM",
"DateField": "21 November 2014 23:29:35",
"DateField": "21 November 2014 23:29:35 PM",
```