# curl post request to marketingcloud REST API is returning InvalidOrMissingTo

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, json, curl

Same request works from POSTMAN but I'm getting in troubles when trying curl.

```
curl -d @al.json -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Bearer this_is_a_valid_token" -X POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:this_is_a_valid_external_key/send
```

And the al.json file is

```
{"To": {"Address": "valid@email.com", "SubscriberKey": "valid@email.com", "ContactAttributes": {"SubscriberAttributes": {"Attr": "attr1", "firstName": "Mother Teresa" } } }, "OPTIONS": {"RequestType": "ASYNC"} }
```

The response is:

```
{"requestId":"12a96292-03d1-4a0d-9e3f-1htf4512aea1","responses":[{"recipientSendId":"","hasErrors":true,"messages":["InvalidOrMissingTo"]}]}
```

I've reviewed [MessageDefinitionSends Rest API successful response but never sends email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25190/messagedefinitionsends-rest-api-successful-response-but-never-sends-email) and [Rest API says email is queued but never shows up in web frontend or sends email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56788/rest-api-says-email-is-queued-but-never-shows-up-in-web-frontend-or-sends-email) but can't figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the incorrect Content-type ... It should be **application/json**

Comment: I just wanted to add that there are a few things that could cause this.  The content-type is one but another is missing the body from the request.  (p.s. @Mario, thanks for commenting on this after you found the solution; it saved me tons of time)

Comment: it's magic man!